# Attaching event handler to DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a tic tac toe game, which is almost complete.  The only thing I am left wondering about is if it is possible to add an event handler for `onclick` from my .js file instead of directly calling it from an HTML attribute. Here is the bit of HTML that uses the `onclick`:

```
<div id="left">
        <div id="board">
            <div id="one" onclick="playerMove(this)">

            </div>
            <div id="two" onclick="playerMove(this)">

            </div>
            <div id="three" onclick="playerMove(this)">

            </div>
            <div id="four" onclick="playerMove(this)">

            </div>
            <div id="five" onclick="playerMove(this)">

            </div>
            <div id="six" onclick="playerMove(this)">

            </div>
            <div id="seven" onclick="playerMove(this)">

            </div>
            <div id="eight" onclick="playerMove(this)">

            </div>
            <div id="nine" onclick="playerMove(this)">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any thoughts on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @gotguts. Try my answer. Hope it will help if I have been able to understand your question and i hope yes. It is working for me.

Comment: I guess my question was two-fold and I was trying to get one part answered at a time. I was able to get the answer to placing the event handler in js using @Courses Web's answer. The second part of my question, and I'm not sure if your solution answers this, is wondering whether or not there is a way to add a condition "if one element is clicked, don't select the others? (Part of this game is to answer some type of question before moving on to the next move).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
document.getElementById('element_id').onclick = function(){ playerMove(this); };
```

For each Div, change 'element_id' with 'one', 'two', ...

Comment: This works for me. I just have one more question. Is there a way to add a condition "if one element is clicked, don't select the others? (Part of this game is to answer some type of question before moving on to the next move). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you use jQuery something like this should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#board div').click(playerMove);
});
```

Comment: But, this question has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: Note the parameter is `this`, your way will pass the event to the function `playerMove`

Answer (score 2):

In plain javascript (no cross platform libraries), event handlers can be added via javascript code with [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) (modern browsers) or `attachEvent` (older versions of IE).

Here's a simple function that adds an event handler in a cross browser fashion:

```
// add event cross browser
function addEvent(elem, event, fn) {
    if (elem.addEventListener) {
        elem.addEventListener(event, fn, false);
    } else {
        elem.attachEvent("on" + event, function() {
            // set the this pointer same as addEventListener when fn is called
            return(fn.call(elem, window.event));   
        });
    }
}
```

Example usage (called after the page DOM has loaded):

```
addEvent(document.getElementById("one"), 'click', playerMove);
```

Or, to install event handlers for all the board divs, you could do this:

```
var divs = document.getElementById("board").children;
for (var i = 0, len = divs.length; i < len; i++) {
    // element nodes only
    if (divs[i].nodeType === 1) {
        addEvent(divs[i], 'click', playerMove);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should really consider using jQuery for this. If you were using jQuery, this would have been as simple as:

```
$('#board > div').click(playerMove);
```

In case you want to stick with vanilla JS, you can do:

```
var items = document.getElementById('board').children;
for(x in items) {
    items[x].onclick = function() {
        playerMove(items[x]);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
document.getElementById('one').onclick();
```

For binding the event handler in js file:

```
var board = document.getElementById('board'),
      divs = board.getElementsByTagName('div'),
      i, len = divs.length;
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      divs[i].onclick = function() {
           playerMove(this); 
      };
}
```

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee This depends on the op's requirement.

Comment: It seems like he wants to attach the same function to all of the divs

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee Updated for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is in following 5 lines. Try it :) If someone copies/converts my code in new post or my post to j-query, That is welcome with no problem.

```
var yourDivID = document.getElementById('your_Div_ID');
yourDivID.addEventListener('click', function (){  playerMove(this); }, false);
function playerMove(divElement)
{
    alert(divElement.id);
}
```

I have tried to put complete demo **[Here on jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/samiciit/EhYY6/#username)**, **You can click any div out of nine to check its event** if link does not work, then you can check the following code (working for me WIN7 and FireFox)

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Add Events Dynamically </title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function add_DivClick_Events() {
        var nodes = document.getElementById('board').childNodes;
        for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 1) {
                nodes[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
                    playerMove(this);
                }, false);
            }
        }    
    }
    function playerMove(divElement)
    {
        alert(divElement.id);
    }  
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    #board div
    {
        width:20px;
        height:20px;
        border:2px solid;        
    }
    </style>
</head>
     <body onload='add_DivClick_Events()'>   
        <div id="left">
        <div id="board">
            <div id="one">

            </div>
            <div id="two">

            </div>
            <div id="three">

            </div>
            <div id="four">

            </div>
            <div id="five">

            </div>
            <div id="six">

            </div>
            <div id="seven">

            </div>
            <div id="eight">

            </div>
            <div id="nine">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>    
 </html>
```