# Prevent browser back button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to figure out a way that when a user clicks on the escape button and when the user clicks the browser back button, it just redirects to the webpage that it replace. I found the code that works kinda well:

```js
function getAway() {
  // Get away right now
  window.open("http://weather.com", "_newtab");

  // Replace current site with another benign site
  window.location.replace('http://google.com');

  //Prevents back button from going back to website 


}

$(function() {

  $("#get-away").on("click", function(e) {
    getAway();
  });

  $("#get-away a").on("click", function(e) {
    // allow the (?) link to work
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});

function checkStorage() {

  var myVar = sessionStorage.getItem("myVar");
  if (myVar != undefined) {
    window.history.forward();
  }
}

function check() {
  sessionStorage.setItem("myVar", "true");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="keywords" content="Spanish Chat, Child Abuse Chat, Child Abuse Support, Child Abuse Discussion, Suvivor, chat, discussion, support, domestic violence, violencia domestica, abuso infantil, abuso de niño">
  <meta name="description" content="Moderated chat rooms for victims and survivors of child abuse and domestic violence.">
  <title>Yes ICAN: International Child Advocacy Network</title>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

  <!-- <script type="text/javascript">
      alert("SAFETY ALERT: If you are in danger, please use a safer computer, or call 911, your local hotline, or the U.S. National Domestic Violence Hotline at 1-800-799-7233 and TTY 1-800-787-3224. See more technology safety tips online.")
    </script>-->


  <script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-27303610-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

    (function() {
      var ga = document.createElement('script');
      ga.type = 'text/javascript';
      ga.async = true;
      ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
      var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
  </script>
</head>

<body onLoad="initialize(); checkStorage();">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <!--Main Navigation Bar-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
            <img alt="site logo" id="navlogo" src="img/logo_short_sm.png" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Home page" target="_blank" href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Group Facilitated Chat Room" href="gethelp.html">Get Help</a>
            </li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Message Board Community" href="community-rules.html">Community Forums</a>
            </li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Learn More About Abuse" href="aboutabuse.html">About Abuse</a>
            </li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Learn More About YesICAN" href="about-us.html">About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li><a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Opportunities to volunteer, donate, and get involved!" href="get-involved.html">Get Involved</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <!--Right side of navigation bar-->
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
              <div class="btn btn-lg btn-danger donate-nav"><a target="_blank" href="https://donatenow.networkforgood.org/yesican?code=Homepage">Donate <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

    </nav>
    <!--END NAVIGATION-->
    <img id="banner" alt="home page banner" src="img/banner.jpg" />
    <div id="content">
      <section class="col-md-4">

      </section>
      <section class="col-md-8">
        <!--Left column content goes here-->
        <h2>Our Mission<small><br>Working World Wide to Stop the Silence and Cycle of Abuse</small></h2>
        <p>The International Child Advocacy Network, Inc. (YesICAN) is a leading global provider of online information for those who have issues around child abuse. It is our mission to work worldwide to break the silence and cycle of abuse. <strong><em>We</em> believe</strong> that
          child abuse could cease to exist if everyone had the capability to receive accurate, up-to-date information about abuse and then had the capacity to receive assistance and support to change.</p>
        <h2>How We Make a Difference</h2>
        <p>Our website provides information, statistics, and definitions of abuse. We also have the <a href="community-rules.html"><em>Yes</em>ICAN Community</a> where individuals who have questions regarding child abuse and domestic violence can join with
          others to discuss various concerns and ideas around these topics.</p>
        <p>The premier service of our organization is our <a href="chat-schedule.html">facilitated chat</a> groups. <strong>In these groups we offer an opportunity for abused children and adults to speak with others and to get council and support from trained facilitators.</strong> These
          facilitators have gone through a 60-hour training lead by a Licensed Therapist. To date, we have had over 44,000 participants in our chat rooms. We run specialized chat groups for teens, adult-survivors, victims of domestic violence, individuals
          who are in close relationship with abuse survivors and parents.</p>
        <h2>Our Current Focus</h2>
        <p>Our focus for now, is the development of an on-line parenting program. In this 6-8 week program, individuals will receive training in non-violent parenting. This training will include dynamics of both physical and emotional development, and appropriate
          discipline. In addition, each member of the program will have access to support groups where the topic of each weeks' training session will be discussed. During this time specific issues and concerns that come up for each participant will be
          shared in a safe and supportive environment.</p>
        <p>It is our hope that in the future, we will provide an international support forum, specifically targeting military personnel and their dependents that are based outside of the United States.</p>
      </section>
      <section class="col-md-4">

      </section>
      <section class="col-md-4" style="background-color:#eceef1; border-radius:10px;">
        <!--Right column content goes here-->
        <h2>Annual Bowling Event</h2>
        <a href="files/2015_Bowling%20Flyer_low_res.pdf" target="_blank">
          <div style="text-align:center; margin-top:30px;">
            <img src="img/2015_Bowling%20Flyer_th.jpg" alt="flyer thumbnail">
        </a>
        <br>
        <a href="https://donatenow.networkforgood.org/yic2015bowling" target="_blank">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Buy Tickets</button>
        </a>
        <br><small><a href="files/2015_Bowling%20Flyer_low_res.pdf" target="_blank">Click to see event details</a></small>
        </div>
        <br>
        <p>This Sunday <strong>June 14</strong>, come join your favorite <b>Star Wars</b> characters at the International Child Advocacy Network's <strong>Annual Bowling Fundraiser and Silent Auction!</strong>
        </p>
        <br>
        <h2>In Memorial</h2>
        <a href="memorial.html">
          <img alt="Memorial List" src="img/memorial_list.jpg" />
        </a>
        <p>We keep <a href="memorial.html">this list in honor of the children</a> who have died from the injuries infliected upon them as a result of child abuse.</p>
        <br>
        <h2>Missing Children<br><small>Alert Cases</small></h2>
        <section style="border: #cfd1d4 solid 1px; border-radius:2%; padding:5px;">
          <!-- start feedwind code -->
          <script type="text/javascript">
            document.write('\x3Cscript type="text/javascript" src="' + ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'feed.mikle.com/js/rssmikle.js">\x3C/script>');
          </script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            (function() {
              var params = {
                rssmikle_url: "http://www.missingkids.com/missingkids/servlet/XmlServlet?act=rss&LanguageCountry=en_US&orgPrefix=NCMC",
                rssmikle_frame_width: "100%",
                rssmikle_frame_height: "400",
                frame_height_by_article: "0",
                rssmikle_target: "_blank",
                rssmikle_font: "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",
                rssmikle_font_size: "12",
                rssmikle_border: "off",
                responsive: "off",
                rssmikle_css_url: "",
                text_align: "left",
                text_align2: "left",
                corner: "off",
                scrollbar: "on",
                autoscroll: "off",
                scrolldirection: "up",
                scrollstep: "2",
                mcspeed: "20",
                sort: "Off",
                rssmikle_title: "off",
                rssmikle_title_sentence: "",
                rssmikle_title_link: "",
                rssmikle_title_bgcolor: "#FF0000",
                rssmikle_title_color: "#FFFFFF",
                rssmikle_title_bgimage: "",
                rssmikle_item_bgcolor: "#eceef1",
                rssmikle_item_bgimage: "",
                rssmikle_item_title_length: "55",
                rssmikle_item_title_color: "#0066FF",
                rssmikle_item_border_bottom: "on",
                rssmikle_item_description: "on",
                item_link: "off",
                rssmikle_item_description_length: "150",
                rssmikle_item_description_color: "#666666",
                rssmikle_item_date: "gl1",
                rssmikle_timezone: "Etc/GMT",
                datetime_format: "%b %e, %Y %l:%M:%S %p",
                item_description_style: "text+tn",
                item_thumbnail: "full",
                item_thumbnail_selection: "auto",
                article_num: "15",
                rssmikle_item_podcast: "off",
                keyword_inc: "",
                keyword_exc: ""
              };
              feedwind_show_widget_iframe(params);
            })();
          </script>
          <div style="font-size:10px; text-align:center; width:300px;"><a href="http://feed.mikle.com/" target="_blank" style="color:#CCCCCC;">RSS Feed Widget</a>
            <!--Please display the above link in your web page according to Terms of Service.-->
          </div>
          <!-- end feedwind code -->
        </section>
        <br>

      </section>

    </div>

    <div class="container" style="overflow-y: hidden;">
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-md custom-height-modal">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:#d3d3d3">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h3 class="modal-title" style="text-align:center">Safety Warning</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <p style="text-align:center">Your computer can be monitored by others. For your safety, consider using a public computer or a friend’s computer. If you are in danger, please call 911, your local hotline, or the U.S. National Domestic Violence Hotline at<a href="tel:+1.800.799.7233"
                class="call" onClick="return probablyPhone;"> +1-800-799-7233</a> and
                <br>TTY <a href="tel:+1.800.787.3224" class="call" onClick="return probablyPhone;">+1-800-787-3224</a>.</p>
              <p style="text-align:center">To learn more how to computer safety, click the following link:
                <br><a href="internet-safety-tips.html">Internet Safety Tips</a>
                <br>
              </p>
              <!--Wording can be better just for the meantime-->
              <p style="text-align:center">If you are not safe, click the following button:
                <br><span class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" id="get-away" id="del_cookie">Escape Button</span>
                </br>
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <p class="text-center"><a href="" class="btn btn-default" class="btn pull-middle" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--End of Modal container-->
    <!--<div class="container">

                <section class="col-md-3">
                  <div class="list-group" id="sidebar">
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                      Link 1
                    </a>
                  </div>
              </section>
            </div>-->
  </div>
  <!--End wrapper-->

  <footer>
    <div id="footer-right">

      <ul>
        <li>ABOUT US</li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ's</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="sitemap.html">Site Map</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li>SUPPORT OUR CAUSE</li>
        <li><a href="https://donatenow.networkforgood.org/yesican?code=Homepage" target="_blank">Donate</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="volunteer.html">Volunteer</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="fundraiser.html">Fundraising Events</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li>FOLLOW US</li>
        <li>
          <a target="_blank" href="http://ww.facebook.com/yesicanorg">
            <img src="img/social/facebook-icon.png" alt="Facebook Logo" class="social-icon">
          </a>
          <a target="_blank" href="http://www.instagram.com/childadvocacynetwork">
            <img src="img/social/instagram-icon.png" alt="Instagram Logo" class="social-icon">
          </a>
          <a target="_blank" href="http://twitter.com/YesICANorg">
            <img src="img/social/twitter-icon.png" alt="Twitter Logo" class="social-icon" />
          </a>
          <a target="_blank" href="http://www.pinterest.com/Yesicanorg">
            <img src="img/social/pinterest-icon.png" alt="Pinterest Logo" class="social-icon" />
          </a>
          <a target="_blank" href="http://www.youtube.com/childadvocacynetwork">
            <img src="img/social/youtube-icon.png" alt="YouTube Logo" class="social-icon" />
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="footer-left">
      <p id="footer-slogan">BREAK THE <strong>SILENCE</strong> 
        <br>AND <strong>CYCLE</strong> OF ABUSE</p>
      <p id="copyright">Copyright&copy; 2015 International Child Advocacy Network</p>
    </div>
  </footer>
  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <!--<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/escape-button.js"></script>
  <script src="js/checkStorage.js"></script>

  <!--Testing to see if it works-->
  <!--<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                 if ($.cookie('pop') == null) {
                     $('#myModal').modal('show');
                     $.cookie('pop', '1');
                  }

             });
           </script>-->

  <!--Works fine-->
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
  </script>

  <script>
    var probablyPhone = ((/iphone|android|ie|blackberry|fennec/).test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()) && 'ontouchstart' in document.documentElement);

    function initialize() {
      (function($) {
        $('.call').css("text-decoration", "none");
        $('.call').css("color", "black");
        $('.call').css("cursor", "default");
      })(jQuery);
    }
  </script>
  <script>
    function checkStorage() {

      var myVar = sessionStorage.getItem("myVar");
      if (myVar != undefined) {
        window.history.forward();
      }
    }

    function check() {
      sessionStorage.setItem("myVar", "true");
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

This is what I am doing and I added the html code and the escape button code and the code you showed me

Comment: you could send a no cache header down.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intercepting call to the back button in my AJAX application: I don't want it to do anything!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844491/intercepting-call-to-the-back-button-in-my-ajax-application-i-dont-want-it-to)

Comment: You cannot trap, intercept, prevent, or do anything else with the browser back button.

Comment: @torazaburo Plot twist: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16183056/283863

Comment: Meddling with the browser Back button will likely make people avoid your website.

Answer (score 1):

If after pressing the "Escape" button you want the user to redirect to some  other page and don't want him/her to return even if they press "back" in the browser then here is what you can do.

Include onload event in your body tag as,

```
<body onload="checkStorage()">
    <!--You body content-->
</body>
```

Now use the below script,

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            function checkStorage() {

                var myVar = sessionStorage.getItem("myVar");
                if (myVar != undefined) {
                    window.history.forward();
                }

            }

            function check() {
                sessionStorage.setItem("myVar", "true");

                //the URL you want the user to get redirected to when
                //they press "Escape" button
                window.location.replace("http://www.saumilsoni.me");
            }
        </script>
```

**UPDATE:** If you already have called some function on `onload` you can use the concept of callback function because defining multiple functions in `onload` can have issues in some browser. Here is what you can do,

```
<body onload="checkStorage()">
    <!--You body content-->
</body>

<script>
    function checkStorage(){

        var myVar = sessionStorage.getItem("myVar");
        if (myVar != undefined) {
            window.history.forward();
        }else{
            //call the function here that you previously called onload
            yourFunction();
        }

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure how this will work for the modal Saumil. fairly new to javascript

Comment: @RobertoFlores so when the modal opens you want to go back to the previous webpage?

Comment: so when the modal opens, it will have content and it will give the user the options to click an escape button which when it the user does click on the escape button, will redirect them to another page. Once they are on that page and want to go back to the webpage they are on, they wont be able to. And so I am trying to figure out a way to do that with no success

Comment: @RobertoFlores check my updated answer. Is this what you are looking for

Comment: yes this is what I am looking for but for the onload, I already loading something else, can I add another onload to the body??

Comment: @RobertoFlores to perform multiple actions on load, don't use inline event handlers. In fact, never use inline event handlers even if you're doing just one thing. Learn to use jQuery or a similar framework, or use basic javascript [addEventListener](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12659061/17300) which has been around for over a decade - since [DOM Level 2 Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/)

Comment: @stephenp Indeed jQuery would be a much better option compared to plain JavaScript but as the OP didn't had the jQuery tag I answered him plain JavaScript usage

Comment: @RobertoFlores Glad it helped, you can accept the answer if you think it was helpful.. ;)

Comment: @SaumilSoni it didnt work. I am not sure what I am doing wrong I will try to edit what I did

Comment: @RobertoFlores show me what you are doing, maybe I can point out

Comment: @SaumilSoni I just added what I did and also my html code, hopefully this can help you see what I did

Answer (score 0):

I would implore you to not [break the back button](http://rowansimpson.com/2007/02/23/dont-break-the-back-button/). We've known it is a bad idea to break the back button [since the nineteen-nineties](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/the-top-ten-web-design-mistakes-of-1999/).

Users have an expectation of how their browser will work, when you intentionally break the way something normally works you will frustrate, irritate and even possibly anger them. Many people will refuse to use your site if it behaves in unpredictable or non-standard ways. It is easy enough to accidentally make things hard to use, it is a bad idea to intentionally make your site harder to use.