# How to get the id that called a function?

Tags: javascript, html, css, area

I am trying to do a function that displays different things when called by different ids in the tag area.

I've read the answers to similar request, but I couldn't figure out my mistakes.

```js
function Over() {
      if (this.id == "cc") {
          el = document.getElementById("Box1")
          el.style.display = 'block';
      } else if (this.id == "mm") {
          el = document.getElementById("Box2")
          el.style.display = 'block';
      } else if (this.id == "ca") {
          el = document.getElementById("Box3")
          el.style.display = 'block';
      }
  }

  function Out() {
      if (this.id == "cc") {
          el = document.getElementById("Box1")
          el.style.display = 'none';
      } else if (this.id == "mm") {
          el = document.getElementById("Box2")
          el.style.display = 'none';
      } else if (this.id == "ca") {
          el = document.getElementById("Box3")
          el.style.display = 'none';
      }
  }
```

```css
#Box1, #Box2, #Box3 {
    display: none;
    top: 250px;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-left: 38%;
    position: absolute;
    border: solid;
    border-color: black;
    z-index: 100;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    /* firefox */
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    /* safari, chrome */
    text-align: center;
}

#Box2 {
    top: 450px;
    width: 10%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    margin-left: 18%;
}

#Box3 {
    top: 50px;
    width: 3%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<img src="ticinello2.jpg" id="imgmap" alt="Mappa" usemap="#parkmap">
<map name="parkmap" id="map">
    <area shape="poly" coords="326,196,321,370,424,283,426,197" target="_blank" alt="polycc" href="#" onmouseover=Over.call(this) onmouseout="Out.call(this)" id="cc" />
    <area shape="poly" coords="426,198,554,458,457,553,328,404,324,404,324,375" target="_blank" alt="polymm" href="#" onmouseover=Over.call(this) onmouseout="Out.call(this)" id="mm" />
    <area shape="poly" coords="328,405,324,412,325,675,330,681,451,554" target="_blank" alt="polyca" id="ca" href="#" onmouseover="Over.call(this)" onmouseout="Out.call(this)" />
</map>
```

Comment: You're passing the parameter `this` to functions (`Over()`, `Out()`) that don't take parameters. Add a parameter to them so they are `function Over(e) { ... }` and `function Out(e) { ... }` , and then get their ID by doing `e.id`, not `this.id`.

Comment: @Santi Or, even better, change them to `function Over(this){ ... }`.

Comment: @Santi Actually, he's not passing `this` in, he's using `call`, which changes the `this` attribute inside of a function.

Comment: Didn't notice, good eye @Feathercrown

Comment: @Santi do i have to remove onmouseover=Over.call(this) and instead only use onmouseover=Over()?

Comment: My comment was suggesting you do `onmouseover="Over(this)"` as it's the more common implementation, though you could use `.call` if you prefer that method.

Comment: @LivioBorgogna change it to `onmouseover="Over(this);"` and `function Over(this)`.

Comment: You should consider using JavaScript to attach the event handlers, rather than doing it in the HTML (to maintain separation of concerns). See [the answers to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12659030/215552) for more info.

Comment: @Feathercrown No, `function Over(that)`; `this` can't be used as a parameter name.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Ah, true.

Comment: @Mike McCaughan  i tried your solution, it doesnt seem to work

Comment: Seems to work fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/qLkgt9fq/1/, where are your boxes and is the parent positioned relatively?

Comment: @Pete not the parent, but the parent of the parent is

Comment: @Pete it seems that it doesn show anything, is this the correct way to write it console.log(this.id, " Random words");

Comment: Well, it depends on how you tried it. I doubt you tried all of the answers to that question in 3 minutes.

Comment: @Pete If you mean where i called the functions is in the tags area of a map

Comment: @Pete i've defined them in an internal javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your function definition as follows:

```
function Over(elm) { 
    // get id
    var elementId = elm.id;
}
```

Then, usage as follows:

```
<area .... id="cc" onclick="Over(this);" />
```

When calling `Over` method this way, it is passing the current HTML element as argument.